# Apache server keeping track of user session

Tags: apache-2.2

How Apache server keeps track of user session variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's normally not apache's job to keep track of user session variables, but a task for your application.

Typically, all session handling is based on cookies. The web server (or web app) generates a cookie with a unique value and sends it to the client. In the following requests, the client will send that cookie back to the web server/app.

Your application then can use the value of the cookie to locally (filesystem or database) store the session variables, and associate things with a "session".

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different possible ways. The documentation is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/mod_session.html).